# Derivative of Liapunov energy functional

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $E\left( u \right) = \int_\Omega  {\left( {\frac{1}{2}{{\left| {\nabla u} \right|}^2} + \frac{1}{{{\varepsilon ^2}}}F\left( u \right)} \right)dx,\,\,F'\left( u \right) = f\left( u \right)} $. I Know
that the derivative of $E\left( u \right)$ is as follows
$$\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}E\left( {u\left( t \right)} \right) =  - \int_\Omega  {{{\left| { - \Delta u + \frac{1}{{{\varepsilon ^2}}}f\left( u \right)} \right|}^2}dx}, $$
but I don't know how to get it; I would be grateful if anyone could help me get it.

Comment: There is a lot of context missing. Is $u = u(x,t)$? Does $u$ satisfy a PDE or equation of some sort? Does the integral represent an energy functional? Are you really looking to compute $\partial_{t} E$ or did you want to compute [the variation of $E$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation)?

Comment: Thank you @mattos. $u=u(x,t)$, and as you said that integral represents energy functional. there is no other assumption and for the next calculation, I need to understand how that derivative is obtained.

Comment: Then all you can say is that $$\frac{\partial E}{\partial t} = \int_{\Omega} \left( \nabla u \cdot \nabla u_{t} + \frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}} f(u) u_{t} \right) \ dx$$ under the assumption that $u$ is differentiable with respect to $t$.